# run function on last class only

Tags: jquery

going nuts with all the prev - next - append childs :)

Well basiclly i have two classes with same name.

```
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

And an increment function

```
var howMany = 0;
$('#more').click(function(){
    howMany.find() += 1;
    $(".info").text(howMany);
});
$(".info").text(howMany);
```

Now i want the function to run on the last class only.

Any tips ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector or `.last()` function (Preferred).  Also remember your setting the value of a `div` element so you need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

**Fixed Example:**

```
var howMany = 0;
$('#more').click(function(){
    howMany += 1;
    $(".info").last().html(howMany);
});
$(".info").last().html(howMany);
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/HdP6N/

Comment: I tried that but get Invalid left-hand side in assignment on row  howMany.find() += 1; .

Comment: @Dymond thats because how many a variable of type int is trying to call a function. I updated, however i think your trying to get the value from the text and increment it

Comment: @Dymond your welcome.  Are you trying to increment the value in `.info:last`?

Comment: wound't be `$(".info").last().text(howMany)` better? i'm pretty sure `:last` would start the sizzle engine, while using `.last()` would be able to use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` if aviable.

Comment: @t.niese I'm not sure about the internals but I'll take your word for it.  Updating...

Comment: @KevinBowersox well, im trying to give every last created class an ID.
So i though it would work giving the last element the incremented id :)

Comment: @Dymond ok so my second example doesn't apply, but your going to run into issues with `text()`, it should be `hmtl()`

Comment: @KevinBowersox The last one didn't do the magic, Im running into issues well every five minutes so im used to it haha :) But thank alot. appreciated.

Comment: @KevinBowersox did a short check to confirm it: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ "[...] queries using `:first` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() [...]" (this applies to all pseudo classes, that are not part of the CSS specs or to be correct, that are not supported by `querySelectorAll`).

Comment: @t.niese interesting thanks for sharing.  I guess the other more common selectors will leverage that method.  It must be the odd balls not in the CSS spec.  Good to know.

Comment: @KevinBowersox hmm the last update gives me #<Object> has no method 'last'

Comment: @KevinBowersox I can see it works fine in fiddle, but in my file its messing around. must be something in my script.

Comment: @Dymond Good job, I didn't even think about the `ready()` function

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery `:last`

```
$(".info:last").text(howMany);
```

Complete code

```
var howMany = 0, lastinfo= $(".info:last");
$('#more').click(function(){
    howMany++;
    lastinfo.text(howMany);
});
lastinfo.text(howMany);
```

Comment: You should add a more complete code sample. Good code, no context.